# How to show hide other content fields when we select radio buttons?

Tags: entities, nodes

I have created 2 radio buttons. When i select 1 radio button, then represented field has to display and hide other field represented to next radio button.
When I select radio1, only textfield1 has to display and radio2, only textfield2 has to display.
 [image]

Comment: This can be done with Jquery easily. What are you looking for in Drupal ? A module ?

Comment: Kantu@ What ever it may be..jquery or php..These fields are in my new content type..

Answer (score 6):

This could also be done by using [states](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) that are available in Drupal core. For example you could set that an element in a form should only be visible if another element has the value "x".

```
    $form['my_element']['#states'] = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="some_other_element"]' => array('value' => 'some_value_that_has_to_be_set'),
      ),
    );
```

More examples at [form_example_states_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7).

You can add states to elements in an implementation of [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or add it directly to the form if you are programming it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition.

Comment: Nik, Pls see updated question with image...

Comment: Can we write by enabling php filter while creating radio boxes?